# Best way to do something if map has keys in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, ecto

So I'm trying to implement a query function for a Collection table. And that table HAS to be filtered by :id, but it CAN be also filtered by :rating and :accessibility.

Right now I have a function that is something like this:

```
def find_collection(args) do...
```

Where args can be one of: `%{id: id}`, `%{id: id, rating: rating}`, `%{id: id, accessibility: accessibility}` or `%{id: id, rating: rating, accessibility: accessibility}`. And I need to make these in to ecto queries: `[id: id]`, `[id: id, rating: rating]`, etc...

I know I can make 4 different functions that expect different `args`, but that seems very non-reusable. Maybe someone could give me a hit a better way to do composable "if map has key a do this and key b do this"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might simply pass the argument as is to [`Ecto.Query.where/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html?#where/3). The safest way would be somewhat like:

```rb
def find_collection(%{id: _} = args) do
  where_clause =
    args
    |> Map.take(~w|id rating accessibility|a)
    |> Map.to_list()
  from(t in Table, where: ^where_clause)
end
```

Comment: Why do you need this

`Map.take(~w|id rating accessibility|a)`

part of code here, if you do 

`%{id: 1, some: "some", some_other: "someother"} |> Map.to_list`
**`[id: 1, some: "some", some_other: "someother"]`**

Map.to_list does the conversion to list. Just interested to undersend.

Comment: @VenkateshShanmugham `Map.take/2` defends the subsequent call to [tag:ecto] from parameters that can not be mapped to columns in this particular table. One might pass any map and `from` won’t raise (otherwise it would.)